# Test if string exists in file with Python

Tags: python

I'd like to add only servers currently doesn't exist at file

My current code :

```
 f = open(filename,'a')
 for server in cmo.getServers() :
    print >>f, server.getListenAddress()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
data = set( [i.strip() for i in open( filename, 'r' ).readlines()] )

for server in cmo.getServers() :
    data.add( server.getListenAddress() )

open( filename, 'w' ).write('\n'.join(data))
```

Comment: Thank you , nice answer , but I getting error :            TypeError: set() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Answer (score 0):

Build a list of servers already present in the file:

```
present = [l.strip() for l in open(filename)]
```

(assuming the file format is just one server per line, no other symbols).

Then check if an address is in the list:

```
for server in cmo.getServers():
    address = server.getListenAddress()
    if address not in present:
        print >>f, address
```

This assumes that the addresses you get from `getServers()` will not repeat.
If that's also possible, then build a set of them first:

```
new = set(server.getListenAddress() for server in cmo.getServers())
for address in new:
    if address not in present:
        print >>f, address
```